# "initMap is not a function" error in JS console (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I appreciate that it had been asked multiple times now, but I cannot find a way to resolve it and load the script with initMap function as a separate file.

Let me explain:

I am calling Google Maps API:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap" async
  defer></script>
```

Followed by my bundled main JS file that contains initMap function.

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

And I have the error as in the title.

What I tried to do:

- load main.js first - same error.
- move both scripts in the head section - same error.
- load main.js second - same error.
- split both scripts calling between top of the page (head) and bottom (before end of body) (each way) - same error.

What works is to call the function within the page as per:

```
<script>
   function initMap() {
   //rest of the code
</script>
```

and put it after the api call.

I appreciate that this is the solution to the initial problem of the console error message, but I would like to initiate and call this function from within the main js file as I do with the rest of the JS.

Any help and explanation, would be appreciated :) Thanks

Edit 1 - added more code below and moved function to the top of th main.js file

So the main.js now looks like - webpack blob at the beginning followed by:

```
function initMap() {
    var uluru = { lat: 40.741895, lng: -73.989308 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), _defineProperty({ center: { lat: 40.741895, lng: -73.989308 }, zoom: 14 }, 'center', uluru));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru, map: map
    });
}
```

the error still occurs and the map won`t load.

Edit 2 - more tests done after your comments and suggestions.

When I tried the global scope using the JS bin code it did not work either.

So, I exported manually the code to a separate file and now load it as

```
 <script src="/js/Maps.js"></script>
```

and it works.

It indicates, that somehow webpack and babel are causing an issue... Maybe I should module.export the function somehow?

my main.js (prebundled - for webpack) looks like this:

```
require('./base/main');
require('./modules/Maps');
```

whilst the Maps.js (pre-bundled) does not have any export at the end.

Comment: can we see some code of main.js? is initMap() at the beginning of main.js? move main.js in top of script that loads the api

Comment: Ditto as above, share some additional code that can reproduce the issue

Comment: try declaring this variables in the global scope, see this example for guidance http://jsbin.com/yudifahehi/1/edit?html,js,output , i the coded added all the code related to the API? if not please provide...this looks like a simple issue but hard to solve with no working sample

Comment: Move the script tag, that includes your main.js, before the Google API script tag

Comment: @r3dst0rm that did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

The problem is with webpack that does not give a initMap a global scope.

A couple of solutions:

- add `window.initMap = initMap;` to the end of the Maps.js to give it a global scope
- add object `var initMapObj = require('./modules/Map'); initMapObj.initMap();`

more to read:

[How to use Webpack with Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575637/how-to-use-webpack-with-google-maps-api)

[Webpack: How to export a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257898/webpack-how-to-export-a-function)

[Export function in webpack bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212830/export-function-in-webpack-bundle)